# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mywidget is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading an external script in shopify.

```
<script type=text/javascript src=https://www.domain.com/static/../survey.min.js></script>
```

and I have a jquery in the body as

```
<script type=text/javascript>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someID').mywidget({val: data});
});
```

but I'm getting

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mywidget is not a function(…)

`mywidget` is a function in the external js file. It works fine in a normal html file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the script is already loaded by the time document ready is called?

Comment: your sequence of adding files should be as below <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.domain.com/static/../survey.min.js'></script>   <script type=text/javascript>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#someID').mywidget({val: data});
});

Comment: paste the url of the ext js file here

Comment: i tried it with $( window ).on( "load" ) also

Comment: paste the url here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you've defined jQuery in either of your scripts correctly... I don't see the correct SRC. Try finding the latest version of jQuery and using its URL as the `<script>`'s SRC.